# can we process two different SSAS cubes solutions on the same database

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

Can we store different ssas cube solutions in one database. If yes What happens when we try to process one cube (considering there are many other cubes in the same database). Will the newly processed cube washes out the other cube solutions in the database ?

I don't quite understand this store concept and the deployment concept of multiple ssas projects on the same database.

Can somebody please point me to write article explaining the same or give me a write understanding here.

TIA

Comment: Yes you can create multiple cubes. It would not affect other cubes.

Comment: What happens when we deploy a cube, dose it effect the other cube (considering both the cubes are independent and do not share any dimension.).

Comment: The problem we are having here is , when i am deploying my cube and if one of my colleague is build his cube and when ever he deploys it's affecting my deployment.

Comment: Also both the cubes are in two different solutions. they are not with in the same project

Comment: You cannot have two different SSAS solutions, deploying different cubes to same SSAS database.